# Shell Script - No echo and no errors

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, sh

I'm not sure why i'm not getting any error or any echoed information from this script. It's one of those exercises where we are supposed to correct mistakes in the script. I just need a nudge to point me in the right direction.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo 

while [ "$CHOICE" = "y" ]
do

    # Rocket ship count down code
    for num in {1..5}
    do
        echo "$num ..."
        sleep 1
    done

    echo
    echo -n 'We have main engine start.'

    # Rocket ship powering up
    for num in {1..3}
    do
        echo -n ". "
        sleep 1
    done
    # End rocket ship powering up loop

    echo -e '\e[1;31mlift off!\e[0m'
    echo

    # Loop to build rocket ship
    ################################################## Do not alter the code between these hash marks ###################################################
    for rocket_ship_part in  '\e[1;30m    A   \e[0m' '\e[1;30m   / \  \e[0m' '\e[1;30m   |=|  \e[1;30m' '\e[1;30m   |\e[1;31mU\e[0m\e[1;30m|' \
    '\e[1;30m   |\e[1;34mS\e[0m\e[1;30m|' '\e[1;30m   |\e[1;32mA\e[0m\e[1;30m|' '\e[1;30m  _|=|_  ' '\e[1;30m / | | \ ' '\e[1;30m | \|/ | ' \
    '\e[1;30m |/"\e[1;31m"\e[0m"\| ' '\e[1;31m   """ \e[0m' '\e[1;31m   """ \e[0m' '\e[1;31m    " \e[0m' '\e[1;31m    " \e[0m' '\e[1;31m    . \e[0m' \
    '\e[1;31m    . \e[0m' '\e[1;31m    . \e[0m' '\e[0;31m    . \e[0m' '\e[0;31m    . \e[0m' '\e[0;30m    . \e[0m' '\e[0;30m    . \e[0m'
    ################################################## Do not alter the code between these hash marks ###################################################
    do
        echo -e "$rocket_ship_part"
        sleep 1
    done

    # Up, up and away!
    for altitude in {1..30}
    do
        echo
        sleep 0.5
    done
    clear
    echo 'To the stars and beyond!'
    echo
    echo -n "Do ypu want to launch the rocket again? (y/n) "
    read CHOICE
    clear
done
```

Comment: `$CHOICE` is never `y`, so it never enters the loop.

Comment: @meatspace: Instead of pointing into the direction, you solved the problem.

Comment: Well, the nudge would have been "What the hell is the value of `$CHOICE` at the beginning of the script?", but that would have made the question are rhetorical one...(and note: the professors are getting better, that isn't an error that would be caught by [ShellCheck.net](https://shellcheck.net))

Comment: But you got to admit the rocket ascii-art is kind of cool `:)` (just ditch the clears and set the cursor 18 lines above the bottom to start -- for full effect)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Well, **one** nudge would have been ... - not **the** nudge. So you might think harder about didactic nudges that could work. Finding one which wouldn't work isn't sufficient to prove, that there is none. :) I enjoyed the take off too - coulnd't resist, but would decrease the sleep intervall, and it shouldn't be so linear, but escalating, imho. Didn't analyze the code, however.

Comment: Yes, I was being a bit facetious earlier. A better one would have been "What would the value of `CHOICE` need to be to enter the loop? and.. how would it get set?"

Comment: Or "set x; ./script.sh; set +x", or asking for conditions to enter a loop, or just more subtile: "Would it run, if you modify the condition to 'while [ "$CHOICE" = "n" ]'"?

Comment: Good grief. Thank you all for pointing out the infuriatingly simply answer.

Comment: And, instead of the 30 in `for altitude in {1..30}` you may want to use the value of `tput lines`.  Compliments to the one that made the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

`$CHOICE` is never `y`, so it never enters the `while`-loop.